# Running javascript code with html form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, submit

Hey, I'm using a html form that is used to log people into my website, I am building it so it uses AJAX (jQuery) but I'm having some problems.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function validateLoginDetails() {
    $('[name=loginUser]').click(function() {
        $("#mainWrap").css({ width:"600px", height:"200px" });
        $("#interfaceScreen").load("modules/web/loginForm.php?username=" + encodeURIComponent(username) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password));
    });
}
```

Here is the html form:

```
<form id="formLogin" name="loginUser" method="post">
    Username<br /><input id="username" name="username" type="text" maxlength="30" style="width:160px; border:solid 1px #444444;" /><br /><br />
    Password<br /><input id="password" name="password" type="password" maxlength="50" style="width:160px; border:solid 1px #444444;" /><br /><br />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Play" style="width:100px; background:#FFFFFF; border:solid 1px #444444;" />
</form>
```

The problem is, when I submit the form it runs the code but then goes back to how it was before, this may sound weird but I can tell because I can see it changing the div size and then right after reverting back to its original size.

Any ideas?

EDIT: If I run the code with the below link for example then it works fine.

```
<a href="#" name="loginUser">Clicky</a>
```

Comment: Why are you binding to `click` on a `<form>` element? Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return false from your handler so that it doesn't perform the actual form post after doing the AJAX call.

Here's what I would do.

```
$(function() {
     $('#formLogin').submit( function() {
         $('#mainWrap').css( { width: '600px', height: '200px' });
         $.post( 'modules/web/loginForm.php',
                 $(this).serialize(),
                 function(data) {
                     $('#interfaceScreen').html(data);
                 }
         );
         return false;
     });
});
```

Note that I'm using a post to make sure that the URL (including the username and password) doesn't end up exposed in the web logs.  I'm also assuming that the page containing the form was loaded via https and, thus, the post will be secured as well.

Comment: Ok.  So, we're missing some code here.  I was assuming that this was a function that ran on form submit, but now I have no idea how or where it's being invoked.  What threw me off was the name of the function -- validateLoginDetails.  Turns out that it just sets up a click handler.  Inside the click handler, presumably is where you should be returning false.  I'll update -- and you really ought to change the name of the function.  Also, I'd have the function run on form submit instead of from a click since the form might get submitted via a return in a text input as well.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure tvanfosson is on the right path. Try moving up the return false into the click function or try canceling the event.

```
$('[name=loginUser]').click(function() {
    //do stuff
    return false;
});

or

$('[name=loginUser]').click(function(e) {
    e.cancel();
});
```

Comment: They don't help either, I think you both might have not understood my situation properly.

Comment: I'm confused then. Presumably when you execute the code from a normal hyperlink, it works just because the ajax call jQuery calls the load() function to plug in some data and that's that.

When you're doing it from the FORM however, jQuery does it's thing, but the FORM still submits. When it submits, the page posts back itself and refreshes server side and thus you're back where you started.

If that sounds, right - then you do indeed need to stop the form from submitting. I would move the change your .click() handler on the form to a .submit() handler and then try canceling it.

Answer (score 0):

First, did you confirm that your .php file is returning content and not an error?  If you are inserting content (with `$load`), you should not trigger the CSS commands on the div until your expected content (from load) has returned successfully e.g. use callback.  Also, I would suggest using `.submit()`, a form specific function, with a direct reference to the form tag and/or id to speed things up (not making jquery search as many things in the DOM).

```
< style >

.loadReg{ width:[yourBeginWidth]; height:[yourBeginHeight];}

.loadSuccess{ width:600px; height:200px;}

< / style >

function validateLoginDetails() {
  $('#formLogin').submit(function() {
    // using load(url,{data:toPOST},callback(if successful));

    $("#interfaceScreen").load("modules/web/loginForm.php?",
    {"username": encodeURIComponent(username), "password": encodeURIComponent(password)},
    function(){$("#mainWrap").toggleClass('loadSuccess');} 
    );// end load

  });// end submit

  return false;
}
```

This could be even more efficient and less obtrusive, but wanted to leave it recognizable.  The other guys are right...if your Div is returning to its original size...it is because the page is being allowed to reload...in which case your initial DIV width/height are applied by the browser...as your alternate width/height are only applied by jquery onsubmit.

To recap:

1. assign submit event to form directly
2. use `$load` built-in ability to pass the value pairs is object `{name:val}`
3. move CSS to unobtrusive state vs buried in code
4. trigger CSS if successful
5. stop page from reloading and resetting display

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a form submission, you should really opt for the .form() event handler, rather than a .click() event handler. With the former, if the form is submitted via any other methods, your checks will still run, whereas click depends on that one single element firing an action. You'll also need to return false or preventDefault() on this event, so your function actually fires correctly.

The other thing (and this may be minuscule/unimportant based on the code sampling you've provided) is that you're binding that event handler in a function that has to be called - why not load it on document ready, like so (see below)?

I'd rework your code like this, personally:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formLogin').submit(function() {
        $("#mainWrap").css({ width:"600px", height:"200px" });
        $("#interfaceScreen").load("modules/web/loginForm.php?username=" + encodeURIComponent(username) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password));
        return false;
    });
});
```